# Finding 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find 2nd order non homogeneous linear differential equation for which $y_1(x)=x^2$ , $y_2(x)=x^2+e^{2x}$  and $y_3(x)=1+x^2+e^{2x}$ are solution.

Don't know exactly how I should start?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The form of your equation (moving the nonhomogeneous term to the left-hand side) is 
$$  c_1(x) y''(x) + c_2(x) y'(x) + c_3(x) y(x) + c_4(x) = 0  $$
Plug your solutions into this.  You will find that $y_2$ and $y_3$ immediately constrain $c_3$.  Then $y_1$ and $y_2$ give a relation between $c_1$ and $c_2$, so rewrite the form using the relation to replace $c_2$s with an expression in $c_1$.  Then $y_1$ gives a relation between $c_1$ and $c_4$.  You now have an equation where the coefficients depend only on $c_1$, so pick your favorite $c_1$.  (I usually pick $c_1(x) = 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ be real numbers such that $$Ay+By'+Cy''$$ is the same for your three functions.

From the equation for $y_2$ and $y_3$ you get $A=0$.

From the equation for $y_1$ and $y_2$ you then get $B=-2C$.

A simple solution is therefore $$y''-2y'=2-4x.$$